# How to get the selected features - javascript api

Tags: features, geocortex

I am totally new to geocortex.
I am using Geocortex HTML5, javascript api
After using identify tool to select features, how can I get the selected featureset in code?

Comment: It would probably be easier to understand what you are trying to do. What I think you are after is using a Workflow rather than just the built in Identify.

Comment: Thanks Tom for the reply
Yes, it is a work flow. The user will select features using identify tool, I need to get a particular attribute of the selected features and display them in a widget.  After doing some trial and error I could find a way to get the featuresetcollection  using the code below: 
app.featureSetManager.featureSetCollections
Wondering if there is any better option.
Thanks
BN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a Geocortex Essentials Workflow, the **Get Selected Features** activity will fetch a selection from the viewer.

This activity returns a `List` of `EssentialsFeatureSet` objects, which have an `EsriFeatureSet` attribute that you can use from within your workflow.

Comment: Thanks mwalker. This was what I was looking for. 
Thanks Again.
Regards,
BNi

Comment: Is there an analogous tool in workflow 5 to the GetSelectedFeatures?

Comment: @dklassen Not at this time (Jan 2019).  There is a Get Graphics Layer Features which can work if you know the ID of a graphics layer that highlights the current selection, but no native activity to obtain all selected features from the viewer.